# Best way to store initial values of a DataGridView to provide reset functionality?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataGridView presented to the user with values populated in the cells. I then allow the user to edit these values according to their needs. A reset button is provided which can then be clicked if they want to revert the cells to their initial values. Is there a "best practice" to how this should be implemented? An obvious approach perhaps? At present I take the approach of having a secondary data structure(array/dict) which holds these values so they can be retrieved and repopulated in the grid. Seems particularly hideous to me.

Comment: is the DGV databound or are you setting the source in the code?

Comment: If you're binding to a DataSet or DataTable, you can use its RejectChanges method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears DataSets and DataTables can provide such functionality when used as data sources as pointed out by Dev in the comments. RejectChanges method can be used to rollback the values of the data. This is suitable for my needs.